# How to animate scrollTop() offset?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm looking for solution how to add offset to my scrollTop function, and I found few solutions but it doesn't work for my example.

My example is

```
jQuery(document).scroll(function(){
    if(jQuery(this).scrollTop() > 300)
    {   
        jQuery('.menu').css({"display":"block"});

    }

});
```

This works fine. But now I want to add offset function, because this div stays when I back to the top of page. How can I write something like 300px from top display:block .menu div?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You have to add top property to the div.Try the below code

```
jQuery(document).scroll(function(){
    if(jQuery(this).scrollTop() > 300)
    { 
        jQuery('.menu').css({"display":"block","position":"relative","top":"300px"});  
    }
```

});

Comment: No unfortunately that's not what I' looking for. This my div is fixed, I can't use those settings. :(